# Automatically Switch between two AdSense accounts based on the author post

Tags: author, account, adsense

We are two managers for one website , each of us have an AdSense account

Can our ad code display in the articles we write, based on the author slug or id?

I tried to use this code in head section , but it did not work :

`<?php if (is_author('author 1');) : ?>
<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-ءءءءء1ءءءء" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>;
<?php else : ?>
   <script data-ad-client="ca-pub-ءءءءء2ءءءء" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<?php endif;  ?>`

any ideas to switch automatically between the accounts, not as a revenue share.

Comment: You should probably enqueue the scripts properly - and is `author 1` a placeholder you put in for the sake of your question or is that the actual code?

Answer (score 0):

So I've broken this up into three parts, it'll allow you a lot more flexibility with adding additional authors if that ever comes up.

`enqueue_adsense()` adds the Google scripts for adsense.

`add_inline_adsense()` prints the adsense code to display the ad immediately across the top of the page, so right after the body tag.

`function_js_async_attr()` is needed to add the async code to the script. You'll have to update the list of scripts to exclude though as I don't know what scripts you have running.

```
function enqueue_adsense() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'google-adsense', 'https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js', array(), '', false );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_adsense', 2 );

function add_inline_adsense() {
    global $post;
    $author_id = $post->post_author;
    //you'll want to adjust the author IDs in the following conditions to match what you need
    if( $author_id == 1 ) :
        $data_ad_client     = '12345678910';//these need to be changed
        $data_ad_slot       = '66677666998';//these need to be changed 
    elseif( $author_id == 2 ) :
        $data_ad_client     = '01987654321';//these need to be changed
        $data_ad_slot       = '66677666998';//these need to be changed
    endif;
    echo '<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width728px;height:90px; data-ad-client=' . $data_ad_client . '" data-ad-slot="' . $data_ad_slot . '"></ins>';
    echo '<script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>';
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_inline_adsense', 3 );

function js_async_attr( $tag ) {
    $scripts_to_exclude = array(); //add a list of scripts that need to be excluded from async - 'script1.js', 'script2.js', 'script3.js'
    foreach( $scripts_to_exclude as $exclude_script ){
        if( true == strpos( $tag, $exclude_script ) ) :
            return $tag;    
        endif;
    }
    return str_replace( ' src', ' async src', $tag );
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'js_async_attr', 102 );
```

I've tested this on a site I'm currently working on and it's worked exactly as designed/intended.

If I was building this for a long term use site, I'd even go so far as to have an adSense ID field on user meta, then instead of running the condition that says *if the author is X use adSense ID Y* I'd just pull the author's provided adSense ID number and only perform the rest of the functions IF an adSense ID has been provided.  I don't really have time to build that out right now though and it's not in the scope of what you asked, but I think that'd future proof your project.  :-)

Comment: thanks Tony, and excuse me,because I'm a beginner in writing script code, what about "data-ad-slot="1234567890"

Comment: You can simply repeat the method.  Where you have the ad ID for each author, simply add a new line like $data_ad_slot = ‘123456’; and then as the variable to the string.  I can update my answer if you need.  It’s a minor change.

Comment: Could the change be fully explained, please?
Is the topic limited to a specific type of ads?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the data_ad_slot as well.  You would simply change those as needed for each author.

Comment: Thank you for following me and for your positive reaction to my exhausting questions
I have changed the required according to the authors and
I added the script in function.php of the theme 
Unfortunately, it did not  work well, and ads did not appear, :(

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I explained it in another answer, please review it

Comment: Hope you are there to help me solve the error?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: There is an empty area above the head, and ads are not showing for both of usة,Note that I modified the code slightly

Comment: That's what you're seeing, but are there any errors actually being reported in the console?  What you see is what I also saw, but I was using fake Ad Sense numbers/keys.  If you're attempting to use real ones and you check the console log, there should be some indication as to what is going wrong.

Comment: I have modified the script as follows
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/365253/186918      Is there an error in this code, given that the added data is fake?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code to suit my site, as I use Jannah WordPress theme

There is no obvious error, but the ads are not running

```
  <?php
/*
Plugin Name: adsense for author post-
Description: Site specific code changes for my site
*/
/* Start Adding Functions Below this Line */
function enqueue_adsense() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'google-adsense', 'https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js', array(), '', false );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_adsense', 2 );

function add_inline_adsense() {
    global $post;
    $author_id = $post->post_author;
    //you'll want to adjust the author IDs in the following conditions to match what you need
    if( $author_id == 1 ) :
        $data_ad_client     = 'ca-pub-1111111';//these need to be changed
        $data_ad_slot       = '111111111111';//these need to be changed
    elseif( $author_id == 5 ) :
        $data_ad_client     = 'ca-pub-555555';//these need to be changed
        $data_ad_slot       = '555555555';//these need to be changed
    endif;
    echo '<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client=". $data_ad_client ."
     data-ad-slot=". $data_ad_slot ."
     data-ad-format="auto"
     data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>';
    echo '
    <script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>';
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_inline_adsense', 3 );

function js_async_attr( $tag ) {
    $scripts_to_exclude = array('advertisement.js', 'br-news.js', 'desktop.js' ,
      'desktop.min.js', 'ie.js', 'live-search.js' ,'parallax.js', 'scripts.js', 'scripts.min.js' ,
      'shortcodes.js', 'single.js', 'single.min.js' ,'sliders.js', 'sliders.min.js', 'velocity.js' ,
      'videos-playlist.js', 'viewport-scripts.js', 'breakingNews.js' ,'fitvids.js', 'flexMenu.js', 'ilightbox.dev.js' ,
      'lazyload.js', 'live-search.js', 'theia-sticky-sidebar.js' ,'tiesticky.dev.js', 'video.dev.js', 'viewport-checker.js');
       //add a list of scripts that need to be excluded from async - 'script1.js', 'script2.js', 'script3.js'
    foreach( $scripts_to_exclude as $exclude_script ){
        if( true == strpos( $tag, $exclude_script ) ) :
            return $tag;
        endif;
    }
    return str_replace( ' src', ' async src', $tag );
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'js_async_attr', 102 );


/* Stop Adding Functions Below this Line */
?>
```